# How to correctly name the windows on a wristwatch?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

Well, I know it can seem to be primitive, but I cannot find a sharp definition. I am working for a wristwatches catalog, and it must be stated right.

Some manufacturers call it a crystal, some call it glass, some call it window.
I know that *it* can be made of mineral glass or sapphire crystal, but which is correct?

Comment: I've always called it a "crystal", though on most modern watches the "crystal" is plastic.

Answer (score 3):

I think ***[crystal](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/crystal)*** is the term more commonly used in  "professional" contexts:

> - the glass or plastic cover over the face of a watch.

From [www.europastar.com/watch-knowledge](http://www.europastar.com/watch-knowledge/1004082393-watch-crystals.html)

> - ***A watch crystal is a transparent cover that protects the watch face***. Note that, coincidently, the word "crystal" is also used to denote the tiny piece of quartz that serves as an oscillator in a quartz watch. These two types of crystals have nothing to do with each other. The latter is usually called a "quartz crystal" to prevent confusion.
> - ***Crystals can be made of any of three materials***: 1- plexiglass (a clear, lightweight type of plastic), 2- ordinary glass - like that used for windows, and usually referred to in the watch business as "mineral glass" or 3- synthetic sapphire . Some crystals are made of both mineral and sapphire glass.

Comment: I would have guessed at "face" or "pane", but this answer seems definitive!

Comment: 'Watch glass' is also an acceptable term, as shown in this [FindWatches](http://www.articlesbase.com/shopping-articles/types-of-watch-glass-779085.html) article. It is the term I grew up with (my grandfather being a clock- and watch-repairer). That sounds like an opening for some dire humour.